# Rank of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Consider a matrix

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\
        0 & D
       \end{bmatrix} $$

where the number of rows of each matrix is greater than that of columns. I know that $$\mbox{rank}(X) \ge \mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank}(D)$$ holds. Then, can we say that $X$ has full column rank when both $A$ and $D$ have full column ranks?

Comment: Let $A: n_1 \times p_1$, $B: n_1 \times p_2$ and $D: n_2 \times p_2$ where $n_1>p_1$, $n_1 >p_2$ and $n_2 > p_2$ with $p=p_1+p_2$, $n=n_1+n_2$ and $n>p$. My conjecture is that if $A$ and $D$ have full column rank such that $rank(A)=p_1$ and $rank(D)=p_2$, we have $rank(A)+rank(D)=p_1+p_2 \le rank(X) \le p$, and hence, $rank(X)=p$ holds if both $A$ and $D$ have full column rank. I'm wondering if this is correct.

Comment: This is correct and easy to show: If the columns of $A$ and those of $D$ are linearly independent, then so are those of $X$.

Comment: Many thanks for your confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the case where $A$ and $D$ are both square. Here we have $\det(X) = \det(A)\det(D)\neq 0$, so $X$ is non-singular. Thus $X$ has full-rank.

If $A$ and $D$ are rectangular, then this is not true. For instance, let
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Many thanks. But I think, in your example, $A$ and/or $D$ is not full rank...

Comment: It is. You take $A$ to be the column vector $(1;0)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm considering the case where both $A$ and $D$ have more rows than columns.

Comment: Here $A$ is the column vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. It has more rows than columns.

Comment: Thanks. But $D=[0,1]$ is $1 \times 2$ vector, which I'm not assuming.

Comment: Then you should be clear about the dimensions of each submatrix, otherwise it is impossible to answer the question. In the general case the claim is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By "the number of rows of each matrix is greater than that of columns", three matrices A, B and D have more rows than columns...